# Почему при добавлении класса JS выдает ошибку: TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined

Tags: javascript

Есть код

```js
let elem = document.getElementsByClassName("miniblocks");
elem.classList.add("blocks");
```

```css
.blocks {
  color: red;
}

.miniblocks {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="miniblocks" id="miniblock1">
    
</div>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему не удается добавить класс к элементу elem?

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` выбирает коллекцию элементов, а не один. Поэтому надо либо обращаться к первому элементу `elem[0]`, либо  через цикл обращаться к каждому из элементов в коллекции